# Looks like a bug in Stack Overflow reputation update

Tags: bug, reputation, live-refresh

I am using Stack Overflow from past couple of years but from few month I noticed a issue like when someone give +1 in my question I got 9 points and my score increase by +9 points. Let us suppose right-now I have 101 points and someone give +1 to my question its increase by +9 point while it should increase by +5 and when I will refresh the page it subtract 4 points. Is this bug in point calculation or only I am getting this issue. Same issue when I got point to edit question or accept answer.

Comment: Let's see if it becomes 106 or 105

Comment: The live refresh won't reduce the reputation, by design.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd But how does one gain, then lose, 4 rep in sync with (and independently to) someone upvoting their question?

Comment: @michaelb958 most likely it was 10, not 9. Two upvotes, one undone quickly after being cast.

Comment: SO this is not a bug? And done by Stackoverflow?